# Implement loader with a timeout in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm basically calling data from an API and handling the data loading with a loader in my html so when my data array.length is not undefined, the data is shown.
But when there is no data it loads indefinitely...
What I want to do is set a timeout if there is no data, something like 10 seconds in order to display a message like "No data found"

Here is my Vue.js template:
[image]

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If there is no data I want to stop the loader after a timeout of 10 seconds, it's written in the question you just have to read it

Comment: That's not what you wrote in the "question", and I still don't see a real question or problem...

Comment: "But when there is no data it loads indefinitely..." looks like a problem doesn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you search how to print a message after 10 seconds, there is this code:

```
function stateChange(newState) {
  setTimeout('', 10000); //10sec * 1000

  if(newState == -1) {
    alert('NO DATA');
  }
}
```